# Using Filters in ImageView

Tags: android, image-processing, jar

I am using the jar file provided from [here](http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/index.html). I want to apply the filters of that library to my image views (ex. FadeFilter). How can I achieve this? I've been googling but I cant find a solution. I know it sounds noobish but please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should apply them to your images and use the result image in your imageView

Comment: how can i apply it on an image?